# Is humidity more relevant than high operating temperatures in hard drive reliability?

Tags: computers

According to [Environmental Conditions and Disk Reliability in Free-cooled Datacenters](http://0b4af6cdc2f0c5998459-c0245c5c937c5dedcca3f1764ecc9b2f.r43.cf2.rackcdn.com/23104-fast16-papers-manousakis.pdf):

> Based on our experience and observations, we conclude
>   that high relative humidity degrades reliability significantly,
>   having a much more substantial impact than
>   temperature or temperature variation.

A [ZDNet article](http://www.zdnet.com/article/heat-doesnt-kill-hard-drives-heres-what-does/) examines the paper:

> - Relative humidity is the major reliability factor - more so than temperature - even when the data center is operating within industry standards.
> - [...]
> - High temperatures are not harmless, but are much less significant than other factors.

Are these results correct?

Comment: I made some major edits to this question because the claims of the OP didn't match the claims of the paper. No-one is saying heat doesn't matter.

Comment: @Oddthinking the article title is saying that !!

Comment: @AnynameDonotcare What kind of evidence would you accept? You are questioning a primary source that examines direct evidence. I am not sure who could contradict that.

Comment: No, the main article you initially quote doesn't say that. It was very confusing. The other article says it in the the brief headline and then explains more fully immediately afterwards, so there is nothing more for us to add. (Hint: hard drives placed in a smelting oven will not work once they have melted.)

Comment: What are you looking for as an answer here?  the data in the paper seems pretty self-explanatory.